# SparseArray getValue syntax error (java/android)

Tags: java, android

I have a sparseArray and i try to get the value of one of the elements. However it says there is an error in the if statement. Am i not respecting android standards here?

```
final Button testButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.testButton);

testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int key = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < stuff.carParking.size(); i++) {

                key = stuff.carParking.keyAt(i);
                Object value = stuff.carParking.valueAt(i);
                value.toString();
                if (i == 1) {
                    testButton.setText((String) value);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: please post your `logcat`

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the unchecked cast:

```
String valueAsString = value.toString();
if (i == 1) {
   testButton.setText(valueAsString);
}
```